# Android beginner problems

Tags: android

I'm pretty new to Android so please bear with me. :D

Well my program should read in a text and after I press a button it should display it at another position. There are no errors and I can install the app on my smartphone. Suddenly it crashes for no reason...

1. What did i do wrong?
2. Is there anyways to find an error without anything wrong? o.O

   package com.example.a2;

   ```
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.View;
       import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
       import android.widget.Button;
       import android.widget.EditText;

       public class MainActivity extends Activity {

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           final EditText Eingabe = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

           final EditText Ausgabe = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

           final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);

           button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   Ausgabe.setText((CharSequence) Eingabe);
               }
           });
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
           getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
           return true;
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: please google how to get the Stacktrace in the Logcat and post it

Comment: From a quick inspection of your code it seems as though you are getting a class cast exception from `Ausgabe.setText((CharSequence)Eingabe);` .. should be `Ausgabe.setText(Eingabe.getText());`

Comment: "adb shell logcat > c:/main.log "            use this cmd you can get the mainlog and filter it by "exception" and you will find what happened by the stacktrace

Comment: Post your logcat also

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
Ausgabe.setText((CharSequence) Eingabe);
```

to

```
Ausgabe.setText(Eingabe.getText().toString());
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
Ausgabe.setText(Eingabe.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is here:

```
Ausgabe.setText((CharSequence) Eingabe);
```

So you must change it with:

```
Ausgabe.setText(Eingabe.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You follow these instruction.

Change this line.

```
Ausgabe.setText((CharSequence) Eingabe);
```

To

```
Ausgabe.setText(Eingabe.getText().toString());
```

Comment: I removed the link to your blog, which is unrelated to the question. Excessive promotion of a specific product/resource may be perceived by the community as **spam**. Take a look at the [help], specially [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)'s last section: _Avoid overt self-promotion_. You might also be interested in [How do I advertise on Stack Overflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/advertising).

Answer (score 0):

```
Ausgabe.setText((CharSequence) Eingabe);
```

Change this code with this one

```
Ausgabe.setText(Eingabe.getText().toString());
```

This code will help you to get the code from Eingabe editText and then convert it into string and then set this text to Ausgabe edittext field
This will help you :)